# ros2 crystal create python pkg

Tags: python, ros2, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I'm trying to port some of my python nodes to ros2 crystal and I've noticed, that

ros2 pkg create did not support --build-type ament_python.

Is this still an open feature for crystal ?

What is the official workaround for python packages for ros2 crystal ?

Thanks for some feedback

Cheers Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311692/ros2-crystal-create-python-pkg/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2018-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an issue to implement support for the `ament_python` build type for that verb: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/125 It just needs someone to take the time to implement it.

Until then you can take a look at existing Python packages and use them as a template to create your own package by hand. The packages in the reference repository are all Python packages.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0